# Would it be ethical to make a bot that would answer stack exchange questions?

Tags: ethics, artificial-intelligence

Lets say the bot would be markov chain based and trained on the answers given previously on that tag. Would the answer to this question be different if it was based on neural networks? Would this change at some level of bots complexity?

Comment: i thought markov chains were random ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this just requires reading the stack exchange terns of service ( http://stackexchange.com/legal ) which require that the subscriber be a person ("individual" is the actual word used).

Comment: Would not following that rule be unethical? It might be illegal, but illegal does not necessarily mean unethical.

Comment: If it provides good answers, then why would there be anything wrong with it? And I don't see how implementation details would matter here.

Comment: Lying is generally unethical.  Assenting to terms of service in bad faith is (a form of) lying.

Comment: "... which require that the subscriber be a person ..." Can corporations have an account on Stackexchange? General AI's? Cats?

Comment: By the time we have a bot capable of correctly answering philosophy questions, Skynet will have taken over the world.

Comment: That bot will continuously argue with the other bot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lying is generally considered unethical.  Falsely entering into a contract is a form of lying. The [Terms of Service for the Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/legal) sites indicate that accepting the terms indicates that the subscriber is "an individual".  The rest of the contract makes clear that the intention is that the subscriber is a (human) person.  A bot would be unable to live up to this aspect of the terms of service.

> Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an individual (i.e., not a corporate entity) at least 13 years of age. No one under the age of 13 may provide any personal information to or on Stack Exchange (including, for example, a name, address, telephone number or email address). Subscriber also certifies that they are legally permitted to use the Services and access the Network, and takes full responsibility for the selection and use of the Services and access of the Network.

If the creator, or the bot itself, were  able to convince the relevant person/people at SE to make an exception or to amend the terms of service, then you wouldn't have a problem.

If society were to change such that bots of whichever sort are generally considered persons (individuals) then there wouldn't be a problem since the normal and legal interpretation of the current TOS would admit them.

In this context, the AI aspect is a red herring; what is important is that SE is providing its services with restrictions.  If anybody/anything is not able to conform to those restrictions they are lying (falsely entering into a contract); a fact that has negative moral impacts.

This answer addresses one facet of a bot autonomously participating in SE; there are certainly ways that a bot acting in coordination with a person, could fulfill the TOS but I don't interpret that as the thrust of the question.

Comment: so you think rules are to be obeyed unless infringing some form of basic human right / need? i think that over-complicates things, it may not be *harmful* to spam but it is unhelpful. against the point of rather than the rules

Comment: OP asks about ethics, not legality. One need not look far to find laws in conflict with ethics, see Nazi Germany for example, which had lots of bad laws. Wish someone would address the actual question rather than point to the Terms of Service, which have nothing to do with ethics.

Comment: @user4894 lack of respect for other people wishes or autonomy? not the best question imho, an answer can be easily framed without philosophy, and in very many ways

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN What I'm saying is, suppose they changed the Terms of Use? Are bots *ethical*? That's what the OP asked. And really, why aren't they? You know we don't directly interact with the Stackexchange database. Our interaction w/SE is mediated by many layers of software already [Browser, network stack, router code, etc. etc.] The anti-bot people are only arguing against *particular algorithms*, not algorithms in general. So exactly what kinds of algorithms are "bad" and which aren't? That is a good question. What makes a bot bad but your browser software ok?

Comment: @user4894 i see no reason to think that bots are unethical, but spam is generally a nuisance and nothing more

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN ps -- How about browser extensions? The more I think about this the more I realize that the Terms of Use are logically inconsistent!! It's not possible to access Stackexchange without a ton of software. Who's to say who or what is at the "end".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41742/discussion-between-mathemetician-and-user4894).

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN I said nothing about spam. You can forbid spam in the TOU without forbidding bots.

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN Not much of a chatter, will just leave it here.

Comment: random answers are spam, nuisance conversation. i'm not exactly passionate about stackexchange, but your dilemma is just stupid. if you wanted to lower the quality etc. of the site, then sure. but it would not be difficult to include a clause in the ToS if that's your problem

Comment: @user4894 if you could demonstrate that there's no ways to differentiate bots / automated submissions and humans, then sure. but i think there are actually legal precedents with the law and automated phone calls, so bots can be defined. "i won't run any additional scripts to automate my data entry on this site". right? perhaps all language is somewhat ambiguous, but that doesn't mean that it can't be understood

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN I am actually reading the TOU word-by-word right now because I think this is a very interesting point. I may write something up if I can tie it in to a sensible answer to the question. But here's a huge point. *Stackexchange has an API*. Yes. That *totally freaking demolishes* any claim that SE prohibits bots. On the contrary, SE explicitly allows bots and provides the means to build them. So the only remaining question can be, who may *register an account*. In other words if I register an account and turn loose my API-using client code, I'm perfectly in compliance with the TOU.

Comment: @user4894 you are deluding yourself if you're saying that the ToS could never prohibit what you mean. wait, what do you mean. etc etc.. i dunno what an API is, but it's not difficult to ask someone to only use the bots that stackexchange provides

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN Not so. I believe that the Stackexchange TOU does not say what people think it does. I made no claim that the TOU could "never" do this or that. Where did I say that? If you don't know what an API is, it's a tool to make it easy to write bots to access the site! I'd think that's a key point if we're going to do a deep dive into what's legal on SE. To repeat: **The existence of an API completely destroys any claim that SE does not allow bots**. The only question remaining is: *Who may register a handle?*

Comment: @user4894 ok but that's uninteresting, i didn't say that the rules of the site are what defines their moral use, so we've gone completely off topic.

Comment: @user4894 "do i understand" i believe it when you tell me. i don't know what this proves other than there currently being no rules against some forms of spam

Answer (score 0):

Easily thought of as a form of graffiti / vandalism, or low key sabotage.

If there are legitimate reasons to do so, then fine. But assuming stackexchange is no monster, just a way for people to spend time or find out answers, then it's just bad behaviour.

Something like respecting autonomy, as we've all (perhaps implicitly) agreed and want to use the site this way, even if you haven't. Or the right to use a website without having our time etc. wasted.

Obviously there are counterclaims, your right to act like an idiot if you enjoy doing so. But the former *seems* stronger, if only because the rest of the site is more populous and serves some substantial use to others.

If that is too utilitarian then I would add that you would be, to an extent, pissing in the pool of knowledge that is the internet.

Comment: **The Stack Exchange application programming interfaces (the “API Services”) are a set of programming interfaces which allow you to programatically query and connect to the Stack Exchange Network.** http://stackexchange.com/legal/api-terms-of-use  Stackexchange explicitly provides the means for people to write programmatic interfaces to the system.

Comment: @user4894 IS IT NOT VANDALISM THOUGH? i'm done pretending to argue about this now haha

Comment: SE *provides the means* to write bots to access the system. Are you not understanding this point?

Comment: evidently not ? you can vandalise a shop that sells paint

Comment: Do you understand that SE explicitly authorizes bots, and provides the means to make them simple to create?